# Multiple server alias won't work in vhost configuration

Tags: linux, apache, vhosts

I have a problem in setuping the vhost in linux.
I have this code in my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /data/APACHE/html/mypage
    ServerName main.store.com.ph
    ServerAlias branch1.store.com.ph branch2.store.com.ph
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I am accessing the mtr_s6.giftregistry.com.ph and mtr_s7.giftregistry.com.ph link in my browser but it redirects to another online page. Should I need to put these links in the linux hosts file and also to the Windows?

What I want is if I access the link `main.store.com.ph` it will redirect to the directory `/data/APACHE/html/mypage` and also to the other links `branch1.store.com.ph` and `branch2.store.com.ph` all of these links are `/data/APACHE/html/mypage`

Comment: Does your DNS actually resolve all those names to the same IP?

Comment: actually these links are not yet added to the DNS

Comment: Try testing by adding those names to your hosts file until they are in DNS.

Comment: hosts file in windows or linux?

Comment: Where ever you are testing from

Comment: but is my configuration in vhost correct? is that the propoer way to add serveralias?

Comment: i added the links to the hosts. But still same effect. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60862/discussion-between-jerielle-and-salparadise).